# Isomorphism of homology chain groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

I am having trouble tackling the following question.

Let $X$ be a simplicial complex. Suppose $X = B∪C$ for subcomplexes $B$ and $C$, and
let $A = B ∩ C$. Show that the inclusion of $A$ in $B$ induces an isomorphism $H_*A → H_∗B$
if and only if the inclusion of $C$ in $X$ induces an isomorphism $H_∗C → H_∗X$.

Suppose we assume there is an isomorphism $H_∗C → H_∗X$. My idea was to use Meyer-Vietoris, e.g

$$...\to H_0(A)\to H_0(B)\oplus H_0(C)\to H_0(X)\to0$$
and the fact that $H_0(C)\cong H_0(X)$ to show $H_0(A)\cong H_0(B)$ (and similarly for the other cases). However I am add loggerheads as how to do this. Any help or suggestions for better ways to solve this problem?

Edit:

Using the hint given below, we can get a short exact sequence of free abelian groups $$0\to H_0(A)\to H_0(B)\oplus H_0(C)\to H_0(X)\to0$$ from whence we can derive that $$ H_0(B)\oplus H_0(C)\cong  H_0(A)\oplus H_0(X)$$
Or equivalently $$ H_0(B)\oplus H_0(X)\cong  H_0(A)\oplus H_0(X)$$
from which it seems reasonable to derive $$ H_0(B)\cong  H_0(A)$$ However in general cancellation of groups fails, so what other information do we need?

Comment: As $H_*(C)\to H_*(X)$ is an isomorphism, $H_*(B)\oplus H_*(C)\to H_*(X)$ is surjective, implying that $H_*(X)\to H_*(A)$ must be zero. So you have a family of short exact sequences.

Comment: Thanks! That simplifies things a lot. Sorry for being really bad at commutative algebra, but given one of those exact sequences, how do we finish off the proof? Is it a purely algebraic proof or does it use any topological properties?

Comment: Leftover is purely algebraic. Try to show that the short exact sequence you obtain is split in the way as it looks like.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the question along those lines, although since we cannot assume group cancellation in general, it still seems quite tricky.

Comment: What I have in mind is using the full power of the splitting lemma. Recall e.g. in Hatcher's Algebraic topology that the splitting lemma does not only give the existence of an isomorphism but the precise formula for the isomorphism from a choice of a section (given by the isomorphism $H_*(X)\to H_*(C)$ in this case).

Comment: I'm looking at the splitting lemma in Hatcher and Wikipedia. I really have trouble seeing this one. Could you write a full answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is an elaboration of my comment.

For simplicity, let me abbreviate $H_*(A)$ to $A_*$ and similarly for the other homology groups. The splitting lemma yields, for a given section $s:X_*\to B_*\oplus C_*$, an isomorphism $A_*\oplus X_*\to B_*\oplus C_*$ given by $a\oplus x \mapsto \iota(a)+s(x)$. (where $\iota:A_*\to B_*\oplus C_*$ is a part of the short exact sequence)

In our case, we take the section to be the composition $X_*\cong C_*\hookrightarrow B_*\oplus C_*$, so after the identification $X_*=C_*$ the isomorphism becomes $A_*\oplus C_*\to B_*\oplus C_*, a\oplus c \mapsto \iota(a)+c$. To make it look more obvious, let me write it in matrix form:

$\begin{pmatrix}a\\c\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}\iota_B & \iota_C\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\c\end{pmatrix}$

(where $\iota_B$ is the projection of $\iota$ onto $B_*$, etc)

Now it is clear that, as this upper triangular matrix represent an isomorphism, its diagonals must be an isomorphism. Especially, $\iota_B:A_*\to B_*\oplus C_*\to B_*$ is an isomorphism as desired.